# CakePHP - Redirect to Cake error page from ajax request

Tags: cakephp

I have an ajax edit button which edits a model.  My model has a critical check for something that, if not present, throws a `cakeError()`.

When this happens, the response to the JS is just the HTML for the error page and obviously this breaks my JS as well.

How would one go about redirecting to a proper Cake error page from the JS?  Obviously I would need to pass it proper parameters about the error as well, which would come from the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to catch the error, return a json error message or status (its up to you how you do that) and redirect on the client side using javascript window.location.

Using AJAX you won't be able to trigger a redirect using php.

Comment: Yeah, the problem I have is that the ajax call goes to the controller, which then calls the model(s) which then throw errors.  The controller doesn't know that the error is thrown, and cake is trying to return the error page for the `cakeError()` call.